# Bumping to the home page

Tags: discussion, support

I am curious as to how it is decided what gets bumped to the home page. Is it an automated process, or manual?

I am looking at [this recently bumped question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17815/creating-an-angular-gauge).

It has three good answers (two of them mine :-) but the OP has not upvoted or commented any of them (no one has).

I look at the OP's profile, and see "Last seen Apr 30 '15 at 9:30", so I doubt that he is going to come back and accept an answer.

Maybe a check for this sort of inactivity could be part of the bump process, no matter whether it is manual or automatic.

I do understand that bumping is for inactive questions which did not get much attention, but there is only so much space on the front page, and this question was bumped at the expense of another, which might potentially have been awarded an answer by a poster who is still active.

No question, really. Just thinking aloud.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The eligibility criteria for bumping are described in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511/236563) on the main Meta.  That question is similar to this one.

The key quote from that answer is:

> Note that the posts eligible for bumping are those scoring >= 0 that have gone at least 30 days with no activity, have at least one non-deleted answer scoring 0 and none scoring more than that, and no accepted answer (also, they can't be deleted or closed).

Then, as stated in Community's profile itself, the choice is random.

Comment: It just got bumped again. The OP, joined, asked this question, and disappeared over two years ago. He was active for only three weeks, his only activity was to post this question, and he is clearly not coming back to read any of the answers. Yet this question continues to be bumped at the expense of others, where the OP is still active </grumble>

Comment: The OP of [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/36628/what-is-a-good-simple-js-templating-solution-for-small-applications) last logged in 3 days after posting it, nine months ago

Comment: Yes, but that's how SE works.  The question, once posted, does not belong to the OP, it belongs to the site.  Whether the OP comes back is largely irrelevant.  The question may still be useful to other people and so a late answer may yet help someone.

Comment: A very good point. I will stop grumbling :-)

Comment: The question now has three good answers, but since none can be accepted unless the OP comes back, which seems to be highly improbable, it will be repeatedly bumped at the expense of other deserving questions. Is there any way for the community to accept an answer?

Comment: @Mawg: I've upvoted your answer.  That should stop it as any upvoted answer prevents bumping.

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to explore this a general topic, as I see this sort of thing quite often.  Is there no way that a "trusted" user (minim xK rep, or top x%) can say "I have tested this and it answers the question, and mark it as the answer? That would surely be of help to others in future?

Comment: @Mawg: Then you should raise it on the main meta as it affects all sites.

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301589/unanswered-question-repeatedly-bumped-to-home-page-op-is-dormant/301591